# Change image button wpf

Tags: wpf, imagebutton

I've created a button, but now I want change image background for it.
I don't want to use events. I searched some solutions, but when I type stype.trigger, then it's bug, who help me.

```
<Button Width="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="75" Margin="0,0,0,-6">
    <Button.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/button-menu.png"/>
     </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: change image when click

Comment: for click you must go with event because it not possible with style trigger